# i want to fill data with MySQL (Month meeting data year-wise)

Tags: php, mysql

i want to fill data with MySQL Data. I have an month table in my database and i've created some customers to test the table but it doesn't work.

```
table 1 is : meeting, 
table 2 is: year.
```

meeting table contains following column containing row of customer name i.e

```
SELECT ID, 
Photo, 
Jan, 
Feb, 
Mar, 
April, 
May, 
Jun, 
July, 
Auguast, 
Sept, 
Oct, 
Nov, 
`Dec`, 
Due, 
`Name of Member`, 
Total
FROM meeting
```

and year table contains following column containing row of customer name i.e

```
SELECT ID, 
`Year`
FROM `year`
```

i have 20 members, i store monthly data successfully for 1 year only, but when i try to store data for next year, the data is store in same month on next year.

following is output what i want

id - name --- jan ----- feb --  total ---  year
1  -- xyz ----- yes ----- no    -----   1   ----  2012
1  -- xyz ----- no  ----- yes   -----   1   ----  2013

Comment: Mabe you should describe what you're trying to achieve and to what end.

Comment: I can't understand your question, please clarify

Answer (score 0):

You should make two tables as below:

**table 1** is : `meeting`

**Fields** : `(ID,Photo,Due,Name of Member,Total)`

**table 2** is: `year`

**Fields** : `(ID,fk_meeting_id,Jan,Feb,Mar,April,May,Jun,July,August,Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec,Year)`

Here there is a relation of `table1.ID=table2.fk_meeting_id`

So you can easily get Year month wise data of particular member.

```
SELECT year.*,meeting.* FROM meeting INNER JOIN year ON (meeting.ID = year.fk_meeting_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create two tables as below in your MySQL database first:

Create table 1 named `meeting`
and add fields for this tables are `(ID,Photo,Due,Name_of_Member,Total)`

Create table 2 named `meeting_info_year`

and add fields for this tables are  `(ID,fk_meeting_id,Jan,Feb,Mar,April,May,Jun,July,August,Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec,Year)`

Now here when you insert record in `meeting` table at that time you need to add that inserted id into `meeting_info_year`.`fk_meeting_id` field and other relavant info of fields `Jan`,`Feb`,......,`Dec`,`Year`

Afterwards,
Whenever you want to fetch all users data year wise you need to fire below query:

```
SELECT meeting_info_year.*,meeting.* FROM meeting INNER JOIN year ON (meeting.ID = meeting_info_year.fk_meeting_id) WHERE meeting_info_year.`Year`=`2014`
```

Comment: there is an error : Unknown table 'meeting_info_year'

Comment: Please read my entire Answer carefully.
I have changed the table name of `year` to `meeting_info_year`.
Its very easy to understand it from my answer.

Comment: Unknown column '2014' in 'where clause'